# How exactly do arrays and for loops work together?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I understand that arrays are used to store values but when they are used with for loops I loose track of what is happening.  I know that the output is 100 because I ran it in the terminal but what I need to understand is that how did it get 100 from using the for loops and the arrays because I'm not sure if it uses all three values or just the first one. Thanks in advance

Here is the problem:

```
public class arrays {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] a1 = {1, 1, 3};
        mystery(a1);

    }
    public static void mystery(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i + 1]) /2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = " + a[i]);` to your for loop to help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the question you're trying to ask is but - to try and help - does it help that each time a[i] is called, it takes the value of i (also the iteration number) at each instance and uses that to find the relevant array index - which is then used for the rest of the computation.

Comment: ok if i = 1 and a.length = 3 then a.length - 1 will be 2, so starting from 1 it will use the index value of 1 which is 1 and apply that to the loop then after that it will add 1 again which will be two but since its < and not <= it will stop at 2?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this method for tracing.

```
public class arrays{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a1 = {1, 1, 3};
    mystery(a1);

}
public static void mystery(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i + 1]) /2;
        printArray(a);
    }


public void printArray(int[] arr){
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  System.out.println("array[" + i + "] is now " + arr[i]);
 }
}
```

EDIT: So what's going on back-stage?

1. for loop initializes i as 1.
2. **a[1]** (previously '1') is changed into (**a[0]** + **a[2]**)/2 = (**1** + **3**)/2 = **2**)
3. i is incremented by 1
4. i does not meet the condition (i < a.length - 1) because i = 2 and (a.length - 1) = (3 - 1) = 2 (2 is not less than 2, its equal to 2)
5. loop terminates and so is the program.

I think what you're missing is that ***i*** does not represent the index of the number 1 in your array, it is the index itself when used in the context of a[**i**] meaning "go to a, in index **i**..."

Comment: i understand that the index starts at 0 but I'm confused on which values would be used when the for loop runs, would it be just 1 since i starts at 1 and the index of 1 is 1?

Comment: in your particular case - only 2 values are used and one is changed. I'll edit my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the method mistery(a1) is called:

**1.** `int i` is initialized to 1

**2.** The condition `if i*a.length-1, which is (3-1)`, is checked; this condition is true;

**3.** because the condition at **2.** is `true`, the code in the for loop is executed:

```
a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i + 1]) /2 => a[1] = (a[1-1]+a[1+1])/2 => a[1]=(a[0]+a[2])/2 =>

=> a[1]=(1+3)/2 => a[1]=2
```

**4.** after the code in the for loop is executed, `i` is incremented by 1, thus, the final stage of this for loop is executed: `i++`, `i` is equal to 2 right now.

**5.** Again, the for loop checks if the condition `i<a.length-1, (3-1)` is `true`; this time, the condition is false: `i=2`, 2 is not less than 2.

**6.** The for loop terminates its "existence", in this case the method mystery(a1) is fully executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you can provide question clearly, you will get great answers ! Anyways :

Try to think yourself.
Array position starts from "0" which is also called as the index of the array.
Here loop is going from value of 
**i =1 to** **i < the value of (array's length)-1** which is i < 2 as length of array = 3

So,

```
for(int i=1 ;  i < a.length - 1; i++){
 a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i + 1]) /2;
}
```

Now **take initially value of i=1** and then **run the code yourself in your mind** :

```
1.. for i = 1,
**a[i] = (a[i - 1] + a[i + 1]) /2;**

gives a[1] = (a[0] + a[2])/2 ==> a[1] = (1+3)/2 ==> a[1] = 2


Important : you have given **i < a.length-1** 
Now, a.length = 3 ok?
a.length -1 = 2 ok?

so i< a.length-1 will stop at i equals 1

So, your program will give {1,2,3} as for loop will iterate from i =1 to i=1 got it?
So only 1 value i.e. a[1] will gets changed.. a[0] and a[2] will remain same.
```